# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Tags: sql

In the past couple of weeks my client's customers have been receiving the error below when running any sort of query on their website. I am not proficient with SQL, so any help would be appreciated.

> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Arithmetic overflow error converting
>   numeric to data type numeric.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) +1951066
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4847051
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +194    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +2392    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
>   +157    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout) +197    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read() +9
>   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
>   +78    System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader,
>   Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn,
>   Object parentChapterValue) +164
>   System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable,
>   IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords) +353
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +164
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) +287
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String
>   srcTable) +92
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +1297    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.GetData() +35
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean
>   useDataSource) +220
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +51
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind() +75
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.EnsureDataBound() +55
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +15
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +80
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +842

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059134/why-sql-server-throws-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-int-to-data-type-nume .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The places to look are either:

1. There is an update query that is trying to change an int (or some other small number datatype) with a larger number datatype (like a single or a double).
2. It is trying an isert with the same conditions.

Focus on looking for something changing values with numeric fields and check to see what datatypes are trying to make those changes. When you see a mismatch, that is most likely your culprit.

Answer (score 0):

change `sum(col1)` to `sum(cast(col1 as bigint))` to change the current column's type dynamically or change it in the table design mode.