# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query having code like this.

```
set @CurrentPatchDeployPercentage = convert(numeric(5,2), (isnull(@LastMonthDeployCount, 0)* 100.00 / isnull(nullif(@TotalMachines, 0), 1)))
```

But when I run I am getting below error, please help.

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Comment: numeric(5,2) allows 5 total digits, 2 fractional meaning 5 - 2 = 3 total digits on the left. A result of your calculation exceeds 999.99 and the error is raised.  Increase the size of the numeric()

Comment: Can you try increase your numeric(5,2) to numeric(x,y) where x,y are relatively higher than what you specified

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why SQL Server throws Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059134/why-sql-server-throws-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-int-to-data-type-nume)

Comment: Hi guys I increased the values to numeric(6,3) but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that is how you want to get your percentage? Should you move your `*100.00` after the division like this?

rextester: http://rextester.com/NNOEH44668

```
declare @LastMonthDeployCount numeric(7,2) = 10.00;
declare @TotalMachines numeric (7,2) = 100.00;

declare @CurrentPatchDeployPercentage numeric(9,2);
    set @CurrentPatchDeployPercentage = 
      convert(numeric(5,2), 
        ( isnull(@LastMonthDeployCount, 0)
          / 
          isnull(nullif(@TotalMachines, 0), 1.0)
          ) * 100.00
        );

select @CurrentPatchDeployPercentage;
```

Also, make sure your `@CurrentPatchDeployPercentage` data type can support the highest number of `@LastMonthDeployCount *100.00` for when `@TotalMachines = 0` and is changed to `null` and then changed to `1`.

[Decimal/Numeric Data Type - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

```
Precision  Storage bytes
---------  --------------
1 - 9      5
10-19      9
20-28      13
29-38      17
```